# Pick page number to display from PageTabViewStyle

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building a tik tok clone, and am having trouble selecting the correct video to play when the user taps on a video thumbnail in the browse tab. Any thumbnail I click on starts playing the first video in the array, no matter what i click.

Here is a gif example: (using generic thumbnails for now, but you can see the price changes work)
[gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaJOW.gif)

Here I pass in the array of video posts on the BrowseView to the VideoScrollView:

```
struct BrowseView: View {
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    let layout2 = [
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    @Binding var currentTab: String

    @ObservedObject var posts: PostArrayObject

    @State var currentPost = ""

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView {

                VStack {

                  Group {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Trending")
                            .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .padding()

                        Spacer()
                    }

                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: layout2, spacing: 10) {
                            ForEach(posts.dataArray, id: \.self) { post in
            
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination:
                                        VideoScrollView(currentTab: $currentTab, posts: PostArrayObject(post: post), scrollEnabled: true)
                                        ,
                                               label: {
                                                   VideoThumbnailView(post: post, currentUsersPost: false).foregroundColor(.white)
                                               })
                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The scrollview where I pass in the page selection is here:

```
    struct VideoScrollView: View {
    
    @State var currentPost = ""
    
    @Binding var currentTab: String
    
    @ObservedObject var posts: PostArrayObject
        
    // extracting AVPlayer from media file
    @State var postPlayer: [PostModel] = PostArrayObject().dataArray.map { item -> PostModel in
        
        let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: item.url, ofType: "MP4") ?? ""
        
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
        
        return PostModel(postID: item.postID, userID: item.userID, dateCreated: item.dateCreated, favoritedByUser: item.favoritedByUser, url: item.url, caption: item.caption, favoritesCount: item.favoritesCount, sharesCount: item.sharesCount, commentsCount: item.commentsCount, productPrice: item.productPrice, songDescription: item.songDescription, username: item.username, modelProfilePic: item.modelProfilePic, player: player)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            let size = proxy.size
       
                // vertical page tab view
                TabView(selection: $currentPost) {
                    
                ForEach($postPlayer) { $item in
                    
                    PostPlayer(post: $item, currentPost: $currentPost, currentTab: $currentTab)
                        .frame(width: size.width)
                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
                        .tag(item.id)
                    }
            }
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .frame(width: size.height)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .frame(width: size.width)    
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
```

I think I need to change the

```
TabView(selection: $currentPost)
```

part, but not sure how to do this.

EDIT: forgot to add the model

PostModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct PostModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var postID: String // ID for post in database
    var userID: String // ID for user in database
    var dateCreated: Date
    var favoritedByUser: Bool
    var url: String
    var caption: String
    var favoritesCount: Double
    var sharesCount: Double
    var commentsCount: Double
    var productPrice: Int
    var songDescription: String
    var username: String // Username of user in database
    var modelProfilePic: String
    var isExpanded: Bool = false
    var player: AVPlayer?
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Init:

```
import SwiftUI

class PostArrayObject: ObservableObject {

    @Published var dataArray = [PostModel]()

    init() {

        print("FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE")

        let post1 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post7",
            caption: "this is a caption",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 44,
            songDescription: "this is a song description1",
            username: "jessicaaa1",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")
        
        let post2 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post2",
            caption: "this is a caption2",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 54,
            songDescription: "this is a song description2",
            username: "jessicaaa2",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")
        
        let post3 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post3",
            caption: "this is a caption3",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 22,
            songDescription: "this is a song description3",
            username: "jessicaaa3",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")
        
        let post4 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post4",
            caption: "this is a caption4",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 31,
            songDescription: "this is a song description4",
            username: "jessicaaa4",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")
        
        let post5 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post5",
            caption: "this is a caption5",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 12,
            songDescription: "this is a song description5",
            username: "jessicaaa5",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")
        
        let post6 = PostModel(
            postID: "",
            userID: "",
            dateCreated: Date(),
            favoritedByUser: false,
            url: "Post6",
            caption: "this is a caption6",
            favoritesCount: 0,
            sharesCount: 0,
            commentsCount: 0,
            productPrice: 25,
            songDescription: "this is a song description6",
            username: "jessicaaa6",
            modelProfilePic: "profile")

        self.dataArray.append(post1)
        self.dataArray.append(post2)
        self.dataArray.append(post3)
        self.dataArray.append(post4)
        self.dataArray.append(post5)
        self.dataArray.append(post6)

    }
    
    /// USED FOR SINGLE POST SELECTION
    init(post: PostModel) {
        self.dataArray.append(post)
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your Model. Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: @Yrb You're right ill edit the post

Comment: I am confused about the currentTab, currentPost variables. With regard to the currentTab, I presume that the `BrowseView` is in a tab that is selected. Why track it inside? With the `currentPost` variable, isn't the current post whatever iteration that is displayed as a result of the `ForEach`? But you also use currentPost as your bound variable in the `TabView`, not `currentTab`. You should be simply passing your Item to the `PostPlayer` Your issue may be that you are passing `CurrentPost` and `CurrentTab` as well, and somehow that is making `PostPlayer` which may make it play the first only.

Comment: @Yrb Yes that is correct, I have a tab structure for the app, the reason that I put currentTab in is because I needed to pause the videos when someone clicked off the scrollview tab (the home tab like tik tok). Maybe this is not the best way to do this? I'll try just passing the item.

Comment: I would simplify until it worked properly, and then add things back in. If you want to pause the video when the tab is switched, you could make that an ObservedObject or a StateObject and not worry about passing it. Just inject it where you need it.